# "this" keyword inside javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this, keyword

I have a decent understanding of the "this" keyword, but for some reason it's still tripping me up in this specific case. Inside the bindEvents method, when I'm binding the submit event to the form, it then executes fetchTweets. I understand that now that it's inside a callback function from the "on" method, so "this" now refers to the form that the event was bound to, rather than the parent object "Tweets".

My understanding was that it is common practice to declare self = this at the top of a method to cache the parent object to prevent later issues with a callback, but in this case it won't work because the sole purpose of that method is to be a callback function for the form submission event.

I know about .call and .apply and even $.proxy, I was just wondering if there was a need to use them in this case, or if I'm missing something obvious. I have this code working using $.proxy, I just thought there might be a smarter way of going about it.

```
var Tweets = {

    init: function ( config ) {
        var self = this;
        self.config = config;
        self.url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?';
        self.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        // bind events as needed
        self.config.form.on('submit', self.fetchTweets );
    },

    fetchTweets: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        var term = self.config.form.find('#term').val();

        // grab tweets from the server
        $.getJSON(self.url, { q: term }, function(data) {
            self.displayTweets(data);
        });
    },

    displayTweets: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var tweetList = self.config.list;
        tweetList.empty();
        // append each tweet to the list
        $.each(data.results, function(index, tweet){
            $('<li></li>').text(tweet.text).appendTo(tweetList);
        });
    }
};

Tweets.init({
    form: $('#getTweets'),
    list: $('#tweets')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `self.<member>`, try using `Tweets.<member>`. You can't do `var self = this` inside the method, because `this` is already something other than `Tweets`. But since you have a variable to refer to the object you're creating, you can just use that. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap your event handler in an anonymous function as follows:

```
self.config.form.on('submit', function(e) { self.fetchTweets(e); });
```

Then don't do `var self = this;` in any method other than the method that binds the handlers. It's safe to use `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and a different approach to the other answer. Much appreciated, it's clearer to me now.